# Error "Trying to get property 'pertanyaan' of non-object" on Dompdf Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, dompdf, laravel-5.8

I have a view and I want to have a link that downloads a PDF.

**View**

```php
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="box">
        <a href="{{ route('pdf',['download'=>'pdf']) }}">Download PDF</a>
        <div class="box-header">
            <div style="text-align:center"><h3 class="box-title">PEMELIHARAAN DAN PERAWATAN ALAT UJI </h3></div>
            <div style="text-align:center">Jln. Kabupaten Sragen</div>
        </div>

        <p> Laporan : {{ $pemeliharaan->status }} </p>
        <p> Tanggal : {{ $pemeliharaan->created_at }} </p>
        <p> Jenis Alat : {{ $pemeliharaan->alat->nama_alat }} </p>
        <p> User : {{ $pemeliharaan->user->name }} </p>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body no-padding">
                <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                        <th>Pertanyaan</th>
                        <th>Hasil</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1.</td>
                        <td>{{ $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['question1'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['answer1'] }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2.</td>
                        <td>{{ $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['question2'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['answer2'] }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The link 'download' has an error.

> Just Showing 404

**Controller**

```php
public function showQuestion(Request $request, $id)
{
    $pemeliharaan = Pemeliharaan::findOrFail($id);
    $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan = json_decode($pemeliharaan->pertanyaan, true);

    if ($request->has('download')) {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('users.view_question', $pemeliharaan);

        return $pdf->download('view_question.pdf');
    }

    return view('users.view_question', compact('pemeliharaan'));
}
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('/user/show/question/pdf/{id}','userController@showQuestion')->name('pdf');
Route::get('user/show/question/{id}', 'userController@showQuestion')->name('usershowQuestion');
```

Can someone help me with the code for the download?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supplying the id route parameter to the named route 'pdf'. That's causing the line `$pemeliharaan = Pemeliharaan::find($id)` to yield `null` and later an error.

Try this:

```
{{ route('pdf', [ $id ] }}
```

In order for it to work you must supply the variable `$id` to the view. You can do that something like

```
return view('your-view')->with([
    "id" => $id
]);
```

Comment: <a href="{{ route('pdf',[$id],['download'=>'pdf']) }}">Download PDF</a>

Comment: in my route i declare my Url with id and save with name 'pdf' // Route::get('/user/show/question/pdf/{id}','userController@showQuestion')->name('pdf');